# image insertion is not working

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

When |I insert the image it is showing the error

> Invalid Offset

This is my controller.

I have copied it from the other page in my project and it is working there - but on the new page it is showing the error.

```
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/upload/'; /* NB! create this dir! */
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
  $config['max_size']  = '2048';
  $config['max_width']  = '5000';
  $config['max_height']  = '5000';
  /* Load the upload library */
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  /* Create the config for image library */
  /* (pretty self-explanatory) */
  $configThumb = array();
  $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
  $configThumb['source_image'] = '';
  $configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
  $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
  /* Set the height and width or thumbs */
  /* Do not worry - CI is pretty smart in resizing */
  /* It will create the largest thumb that can fit in those dimensions */
  /* Thumbs will be saved in same upload dir but with a _thumb suffix */
  /* e.g. 'image.jpg' thumb would be called 'image_thumb.jpg' */
  $configThumb['width'] = 140;
  $configThumb['height'] = 210;
  /* Load the image library */
  $this->load->library('image_lib');
$file=array();
$file_thumb=array();
             /* We have 5 files to upload
   * If you want more - change the 6 below as needed
   */
  for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
    /* Handle the file upload */
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'.$i);
    /* File failed to upload - continue */
    if($upload === FALSE) continue;
    /* Get the data about the file */
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $file[$i] = $data['file_name'];
    $file_thumb[$i] = $data['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$data['file_ext'];


    $uploadedFiles[$i] = $data;
    /* If the file is an image - create a thumbnail */
    if($data['is_image'] == 1) {
      $configThumb['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
      $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
      $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
  }

///=============upload end here==================////
    echo $file['1'];
    exit;
```

Comment: Post your full error message including your form!!

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: controllers/biaso.php

Line Number: 105

Comment: <div class="row-form clearfix">
                            <div class="span3">Bias Pic:</div>
                            <div class="span5">                                                                
                                <input type="file" name="image1" id="case_pic"  class = "validate[required]"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: No need of `for loop` because you just upload only one file

Comment: Read this link https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: any other solution...because i m using the same code in other page where i have to insert more than two images

Comment: Check this [link](http://arjunphp.com/multiple-image-uploading-using-single-input-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

You have set some Image Thumbs

```
$configThumb = array();
$configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$configThumb['source_image'] = '';
$configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$configThumb['width'] = 140;
$configThumb['height'] = 210;
```

Ok grate. and you load library as well `$this->load->library('image_lib');`

so how this settings get config to the library.

---

Add this too

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $configThumb); # configuration variable
```

---

Read this

[Image Manipulation Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html)

Comment: if my answer helpful grateful by accepting it. Thank you